# moving and dropping objects inside one canvas to other canvas in html5

Tags: html5-canvas

how to move and drop an object between two or more canvases in html 5, That means I have an image in one canvas and i want to move this image to the other canvas. 
When I use two or more "DIV" in html 5 it is coming without any problem but when I am using canvas it is not coming..help me

Comment: When you use `context.drawImage` to draw an image to a canvas, that image becomes part of that canvas (like a painted image).  The drawn image cannot be moved between canvases. You can "fake it" by creating an img element whose source is clipped from the canvas. Then you can drag the img element to the second canvas. And finally when the img element is dropped you can drawImage the img to the second canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
#draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>
 
<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>
```